# How to set times for alarms to calendar

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

```
start_alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());


            int hour = alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour();

            int minute = alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();;


            String hour_string = String.valueOf(hour);
            String minute_string = String.valueOf(minute);


            if (hour>12) {
                hour_string = "0"+String.valueOf(hour - 12);
            }

            if (minute<12) {
                minute_string ="0"+ String.valueOf(minute);

            }

            AddData(hour_string,minute_string,1);

            setAlarmText("Alarm set to " + hour_string + ":" + minute_string);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You set the alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            myIntent.putExtra("extra", "yes");

            pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarm.this, _id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);


        }

    });
```

I am building an alarm application.I have successfully implemented basic alarm functions.

From that code I can add one time to my calendar , but how can I add more than one time ? Because I have a list of times i need it to ring

Comment: you can add as many as you want.. just use unique Id for Pending intent.. and you are good to go

Comment: For Alarm Kind of application instead of having multiple alarm, Take an immediate next event and you can set an alarm, Once this alarm receives you can take next upcoming event and you can place an alarm like that you can continue, In that case, you will have always one alarm at a time.

Comment: can you explain me more ? or edit my code please

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran i am begginer can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: @moha, you can check my answer

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran yeah i saw it , but how take immediate next event?

Comment: Where you are storing all the events..? in DB right or in cloud..? If it's in DB you can query and get the latest event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having multiple Alaram, You can take the latest event and you can put the Alarm for that, When the alarm triggeres, you can check for next upcoming events.

In this case you can have full control of every event.

```
start_alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Remove the old alaram and get the new event and put the alarm for that

        }

    });
```

And in your broadcast receiver, check again the latest event and put alarm for that.

Comment: @moha The user can set Alaram any time right..? If I set alarm next alarm after 3 hours and again I set an alarm after 6, how you will you do.? You want to set both Alarms the alarm now itself..? then if I switch off my device and Switch on then what it will happen to my alarm in your case..?

Comment: actually my problem that only last alarm i set  its work ...for example if i add alarms 11:50,13:15,15:30 , only 15:30 will work , i want all the alarms work

Comment: What I am saying is, when you set alarm, take the upcoming event in the events, in your example 11:50 is the next event so give an alarm for 11:50, so will get a broadcast at 11:50 and again do the same process and give 13:15 like that you can continue.

Comment: If you don't want this approach having one alarm at a time, Just change the "_id" in **PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarm.this, _id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);** this for every event you will get multiple alaram

Comment: ok , but i have times in DB and that DB change always by edit or delete !!

Comment: You should stop the old alarm and start new alarm with upcoming events when ever you created or edited or deleted your times.

Comment: thank you , but how can stop the old alarm and start it in same button !!
for example if i write  alarmManager.cancel(pending_intent); it will not work !!

Comment: Should work **alarmManager.cancel(pending_intent);** if you same pending intent with same request code. If you have any issue let me know

Comment: no itsnot , because that button is for set alarm and if write cancel i will not work because u set then cancel same time !!

Comment: I am not asking to set and then cancel, I said if we have some other time in Alaram, We can stop that and we can create the alarm with the new time.